# Raices anidadas ramanujan. Recursión c++

Tags: c++, recursión

Problema: Defina una función, denominada ramanujan. Que toma, como único argumento, la profundidad de una aproximación racional a la expresión anidada anterior. Por ejemplo, si la profundidad es 0, Ramanujan debería devolver la raíz cuadrada de 6. Si la profundidad es 1, Ramanujan debería devolver el valor de √6 + 2√7. Si la profundidad es 2, el valor de retorno debe ser el valor de √6 + 2√7 + 3√8. Su función debe implementar un proceso recursivo.

[image: Foto de la secuencia]

Logré resolver el problema de forma iterativa e imprimir los resultados en el main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

float ramanujan(int depth){
    int subradical = 6;
    int factor = 1;
    float value = 0;
    for (int i=depth; i>=0; i--){
        if (i==depth) {
            value = (factor+i)*sqrt(subradical+i);
        } else {
            value = (factor+i)*sqrt(subradical+i + value);
        }
    }
    return value;
}

int main() {
    float total = ramanujan(3); //Funciona en caso de que sea 0, 1, 2... 
    cout << total;
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que necesito de una manera de implementar la solución que ya tengo de forma recursiva. Y que la función recursiva solo reciba el un parámetro (la profundidad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ver que la expresión es como la siguiente, con **a = 1** y **b = 6**:

[image: Ecuación]

Matemáticamente puedes compactarlo así:

[image: Ecuación]

El trabajo duro ya está hecho. Solo tienes que escribirlo como código y se vería así:

```
float ramanujan(int depth = 0){
    int subradical = 6 + depth;
    int factor = 1 + depth;
    float ram = ramanujan(depth + 1);
    
    return factor * sqrt(subradical + ram);
}
```

Pero hay un problema. El código se ejecutará indefinidamente hasta quedarse sin memoria.

Así que como la profundidad va aumentando, agregas un parámetro `maxDepth` al que si `depth` es mayor o igual, como en el radical tienes una suma devuelves el elemento neutro (0) para no alterar el resultado.

```
float ramanujan(int maxDepth, int depth = 0){
    if(depth >= maxDepth)
        return 0;

    int subradical = 6 + depth;
    int factor = 1 + depth;
    float ram = ramanujan(depth + 1);
    
    return factor * sqrt(subradical + ram);
}
```

Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##bZBNTsMwEIX3PsWobBICqBUSm6RZseEObAbbSYziSfCPVKnqYTgLBwtOHZxGwit73vM3b4aP42PL@TTdKeK9FxIqNVhnJOqarTWNrnvqasa8VdQCoZZ2RC7BOlEy1vQDOjCokfwnUqbIgcbTqxxd9wDzS8xXOMI@PzMIRzWQxVp9TNb8Ks3HSOcNwT6wr@5AsP7DoFAc@4B5gSIiy6Q3yN1ggnbYailbkNaEa7qYooBDHv3spv/CvAf7ZVx2k6CYUeHDhbE4q6Ish3MK84ef40QsH7yDqoLdG7VGWoQeYTRD40kogQL0z/dJaXyn3eJXBHWdQMsilmGk9b1DMfw7Ur5tmMwl2272Mk3Pvw).

Comment: Excelente la orientación para resolver este ejercicio!! Muchas gracias, ahora lo entiendo mucho mejor